How to add workable slash commands to doscord bots
I want to use the discord bot I made and invited to my server.
But how do I make commands or just make it reply to messages in my server.
If you answer both thank you,
I looked at commands by putting in / in the text but no commands shows up for the bot i made, I expected it to give some basic commands or how to make commands but There was none so, I was looking for help. Anyone know how to make the command or commands?

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", indents = discord.Intents.default())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.tree.copy_global_to(guild = discord.Object(YOUR_SERVER_ID))
    await bot.tree.sync(guild = discord.Object(YOUR_SERVER_ID))

@bot.tree.command(name = "sayhi", description = "The bot will say hi to you")
async def sayhi(interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Hey, how are you?")

bot.run(TOKEN)


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
